# Excel formula to add values based on certain criteria

Tags: excel-formula

Can you please help me out in obtaining this Excel formula, had tried but unable to get the expected.

[image]

If the range of A1 to A6 has starting char with S, then the corresponding B values should be added and the result should be shown in a cell.

I tried below formula, but not getting as expected:

```
=VLOOKUP("S*",A1:A10,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? 
This is a simple If Vlookup I guess

Comment: =VLOOKUP("S*",A1:A10,2,FALSE)

Comment: This is *not* a programming question.  See the  [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` will only return the first item.  If you want to find the Sum of cells that match a criteria, use `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIF(A4:A9,"SR*",B4:B9)
```

*'Find the sum of Column B where Column A starts with "SR"'*